# Panel Data Fixed effects regression in R using PLM package with multiple obs/yr

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have a panel data:

[Panel Data set - gravity model international trade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUecj.jpg)

My R code:

```
#importing dataset
df <- read_excel("DataSet_Final.xlsx", 
                            col_types = c("text", "numeric", "text", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "text", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
glimpse(df)

# Transforming some variables into log, for better interpretation and normalization of the distribution
df$log_pop <- log(df$Population)
df$log_dist <- log(df$Distance)
df$log_GDP <- log(df$GDP)
df$log_Trade <- log(df$Trade)


# Dropping unnecessary variable
df$Helper <- NULL
head(df)

df %>%
  group_by(Year, CountryName) %>%
  mutate(group_id = cur_group_id())

panel_data <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("CountryName", "Counterpart_Country_Name", "Year"))
```

Error:

```
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(df, index = c("CountryName", "Counterpart_Country_Name",  :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

```
    dput(read.table("CountryName    CountryCode Counterpart_Country_Name    TradePartnerCode    Year    Export
Belgium 124 Austria 122 1997    1.82394E+14
Belgium 124 Austria 122 1998    2.01838E+14
Belgium 124 Austria 122 1999    1968240347.9
Belgium 124 Austria 122 2000    1931467793
Belgium 124 Austria 122 2001    2067659120
Belgium 124 Austria 122 2002    2260078352
Belgium 124 Austria 122 2003    2684795303", sep="\t", header=TRUE))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to do a fixed effects regression however I have encountered errors which I provided above. How can I deal with this error? The thing is I cannot really drop observations as each country trades with another country for multiple years.

I have tried to find answers on StackOverflow with no solution that have helped me out with this problem.

Comment: Hi 0klahoma, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful you would please share a reproducible example including a small sample of your data set. You will likely get more helpful answers. You can do this best by using You can do this best by using `dput(head(df))`. Edit your question and include the output of the `structure(...)`.

Comment: Thank you David, I have included a screenshot of the dataset. I am new to StackOverflow, if there is a better way to provide the excel sheet I would happily revise my post and include it the correct way.

Comment: Please see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Since%20Stack%20Overflow%20serves%20hundreds,screen%20and%20screenshot%20resolutions%20increase.

Comment: And as David says you can easily provide sample data using the `dput` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @0klahoma for providing more information.  I haven't used this package or done the type of modeling that you're doing, but here is a potential solution.

The Warning seems to be coming from the fact that `pdata.frame` may not be handling an input of **three** indices efficiently.  I can reproduce your error like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(country=rep(c("A","B"), each=4),
                   partner=rep(c("C","D"), times=4),
                   year=rep(91:92, each=2))
> df
  country partner year
1       A       C   91
2       A       D   91
3       A       C   92
4       A       D   92
5       B       C   91
6       B       D   91
7       B       C   92
8       B       D   92

> pdf<-pdata.frame(df, index = c("country", "partner", "year"))
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(df, index = c("country", "partner", "year")) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

It seems to be having a problem when there are non-unique combinations of the `country` and `partner` levels. In other words, it shows a Warning because of levels like `A-C` and `B-D` being repeated more than once, irrespective of `year`.

Here is something to try: concatenate your `country` and `partner` into one string such that you are only passing two values to `pdata.frame`. Namely, make one long string of the combination and one time period. I don't get the Warning with this.

```
> df$country.partner <- paste(df$country, df$partner, sep=".")
> df
  country partner year country.partner
1       A       C   91             A.C
2       A       D   91             A.D
3       A       C   92             A.C
4       A       D   92             A.D
5       B       C   91             B.C
6       B       D   91             B.D
7       B       C   92             B.C
8       B       D   92             B.D

> pdf<-pdata.frame(df, index = c("country.partner", "year"))
[No Warning]
> pdf
       country partner year country.partner
A.C-91       A       C   91             A.C
A.C-92       A       C   92             A.C
A.D-91       A       D   91             A.D
A.D-92       A       D   92             A.D
B.C-91       B       C   91             B.C
B.C-92       B       C   92             B.C
B.D-91       B       D   91             B.D
B.D-92       B       D   92             B.D
```

It is a bit non-intuitive, but I think that the expected input is to have a unique index crossed **once** with a time variable (two arguments, level+time, instead of three arguments, level1+level2+time).

See if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the [`fixest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html) package for your problem. Here an example with 4 FE variables:

```
library(fixest)
data(trade)
gravity = feols(Euros ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product + Year, trade)
print(gravity)
```

**Output**:

```
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: Euros
Observations: 38,325 
Fixed-effects: Origin: 15,  Destination: 15,  Product: 20,  Year: 10
Standard-errors: Clustered (Origin) 
              Estimate Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
log(dist_km) -66754618   14306507 -4.66603 0.00036385 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 116,958,376.0     Adj. R2: 0.303863
                      Within R2: 0.055781
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `index` argument of plm's `pdata.frame` (or in function `plm` directly), you do not specify the fixed effects. You specify the panel structure of the data, i.e., which variable serves as observational unit ("individual") and which variable specifis the time slices ("time"), so two dimensions.

Your observational unit seems to be the county (specified by either `CountryName` or `CountryCode` and your time dimension by `Year`, so you would simply do:

`panel_data <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("CountryName", "Year"))`

Comment: I have tried this before actually, but it gave me the error regarding duplicated id's which arent really duplicates since there are observations with multiple countries over different years. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Not sure if this is now solved... your data does not look like there are more than one observation per country for any given year, but the data's screenshot is hard to read.